# Why Do I Feed So Much? (Jungle, AD Carry, and Support)

Tags: league-of-legends

Me and my friends are trying to start a League Of Legends team, and I got replaced from Top Primary and Mid secondary, and was placed into Jungle Primary and Mid Secondary. But it seems that whenever I play something other than Top or Mid lane, I always feed! (Example: Master Yi Jng: 1/13/2). How can I improve my Jungle skills in both getting kills and the jungle in general? Also, my friend recommended using a tank like Cho'Gath in the jungle instead of squishies like Yi. Could that be a possible good solution?

Comment: This is not a good question... I'm sorry to say it like this. We don't and won't know how good of a player you are. A suggestion to you is: Look at Pro Players and how they play in Jungle, copy their Masteries and Runes, aswell as their techniques. And then just pratice, you will notice a difference after a while.

Comment: I got an answer that seems like it could work, but I understand. Thanks :)

Comment: Make sure you have good vision around place where you farm so you won't get hunted down easily and have chance to back when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ELO is this, and are your friends better ranked than you are? If it's the case, you might have your answer right there... Master Yi is a very good jungler champ when dealing with opponents with a lower skill level than you do. Once you reach higher ELOs, it becomes much easier to exploit his weaknesses. You can circumvent some of them by playing a very mean split-push strat, but if your team doesn't follow that plan, it's not going to work either and you'll just get caught repeatedly.

Your friends are not exactly wrong in suggesting tankier champs. But if you don't understand *why* they are better for you, it's not going to help. More specifically, your friends probably want you to give a shot to junglers that are tanky and have strong engaging powers. By being tankier, you won't be punished as much for your mistakes. For example, if you're Master Yi and get caught in the enemy jungle, you'll die right after you get stunned. If you're Amumu, Malphite or Sejuani, on the other hand, you'll probably have a better shot at surviving, since you'll soak more damage, stun the enemies, etc.

In turn, this will allow you to learn a lot more from the jungle, but also from your laners. By being alive more often, you'll start seeing the gank opportunities a lot more. With your strong CC or engaging powers, you'll allow your laners to get more kills. Once you've mastered the basics of jungling and ganking, incorporating a champ such as Master Yi won't be as problematic, since by then you'll make less mistakes and will get caught less often by the other team.

Finally, champs like Master Yi need to either snowball or split-push to be effective, most of the time. If you can't snowball and your team is not inclined or setup for a split-push strat, you're going to have problems. If you're using a tankier champ with lots of CC, you can still be useful even if you're losing hard. When you go in, if you manage to keep the other team locked down long enough for your team to kill them, people are going to like you even if you die. Honestly, I'll take a 1-13-26 Sejuani over a 1-13-2 Master Yi pretty much anytime.

If you want to learn how to jungle better, I'd suggest you go watch Stonewall008's youtube channel. He's made a lot of videos over time, and they are made with lower ELO players in mind, most of the time. He'll explain his decision making process and guide you through a lot of the basic steps along the way. Some of his videos are also less about gameplay and more about specific mechanics, like ganking from river vs ganking from lane, map awareness, etc. Stonewall008 might not be a pro player, but he still gets to diamond pretty much every season and, if you're Bronze to Gold, there is a LOT of things he can still teach you!

Comment: Thanks for the help! And none of us are ranked yet but I'm a higher level. And thanks for explaining why being tankier helps. Seems like that might really be the way to go, huh?

Comment: @VirusThePanda - Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying tank junglers are the best, either! They have their issues too, but they are usually a lot more permissive and flexible for newer junglers.

Comment: wouldn't you take a 1/13/26 over a 1/13/2 regardless of champions though? The biggest issue I normally see that contributes to players feeding is players obsessing over their K/D/A. They go down a kill or two and then start making stupid decisions in desperation to get more kills and see that as cancelling out all the deaths. End result is one player on your team running around like a fool ignoring objectives and dying to bad fights, often trying to argue the scores in chat at the same time.

Comment: @Anton - Oh, I'm not obsessing about my, or their, KDA at all. They've still died a lot. But from my experience, someone that dies often but sets up plays for his team (hence the many assists) will usually have a much better grasp of what objectives are worth pursuing (and worth dying for!) compared to someone that simply keeps getting caught like you describe.

Comment: @Dungarth - I did not mean that you were one of those people, just pointing out that its not really much of a stretch to say +24 assists is a good thing and that the champion used does not change that. My own point was that the problem for a lot of players is that they seem to think k/d/a is their score and that wins happen automatically if you get a good enough ratio. Its not "how can i win?", its "how can i get lots of kills?" They think its the same thing. You cant play the game properly until you get over the kda fallacy. You can carry a game even without kills, just play Janna.

Comment: @Anton I think you are missing his point.  His point is that a tankier champion will allow his death to actually still contribute.  If he gets caught as a tank near his team, he can just turn and engage with his ccs.  If he gets caught as Master Yi or tries to engage he just doesn't contribute at all.

Comment: @dphil, nope, you have actually missed the point yourself there. Tanky can contribute DESPITE feeding, not BECAUSE of feeding as you have implied. That is because CC is item independent but that is completely beside the point. Ideally you would be using that CC to avoid dying. He wants to play better, not just pick an easier champion, and both of our points will help towards that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few rules in league:

Rule 351: Tankiness is cheaper than damage
Rule 475: CC is item independent
Rule 975: If you build full dmg and are behind, you're gonna have a bad time

That means, if you're on a champ who is tanky and provides a lot of CC, it doesn't matter if you feed a lot because you're still useful. Let's take my Midlaners for example: I'm a really bad midlaner. Like, REALLY bad. That means I will never pick a zed or a katarina in the midlane. I pick something which provides Utility (CC or Buffs for the team) so i can make up for the loss of damage. Stuff like twisted fate (global presence, solid stun, save lane) and ori (speed, slow, shockwave, shields, save lane) are my prefered picks, you should do the same in the jungle.

Never forget: Tankiness forgives mistakes, damage doesn't!

You should try one of the following:

- **Rammus**: A brutal Jungler in my opinion, solid clears with cinderhulk, extremely strong ganks and a monster in the lategame when he tauns the adc and he just kills himself.
- **Udyr**: BEAR SLAP! BEAR SLAP! BEAR SLAP! That's literally all what udyr has to do in a teamfight.  And if you're more confident with him, you can build him with a trinity which just makes him super stupid op. But if you're not, you can play him as a fulltank with iceborn gauntlet and just be the most annoying champ ever.
- **Elise**: While mostly played heaviely magic pen based, she's also really good as a tank. Solid ganks and a lot of base dmg make her a huge threat to anyone in the enemy team, no matter if tank or squishy
- **Warwick**: While not exactly a tank, warwick provides a lot of sustain which can make him a tank. With Blade of the ruined king, Spirit Visage and Randuins Omen he's at his absolute powerspike and will smash pretty much anyone.

Those are probably the best champs for you, there are some more, but all have some drawbacks, like nautilus, sejuani or amumu. I'd recommend one of the champs I mentioned to learn the jungle since they all are really save and provide utility even if behind. Once you understood how the jungle works, you can go back to master yi if you rly want.